# Adding VF page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

How to add a Vf page to a profile? I am trying to add a VF page to a Vendor user. 
Can anybody help me solve this problem.

Thanks
Anu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Salesforce, just navigate to Setup -> Administration Setup -> Manage Users -> Profiles.  Open up your profile, but do not click Edit yet.  Scroll all the way to the bottom of the screen, to the section called "Enabled Visualforce Page Access".  Click Edit in this area, and you can move pages from the left box to the right one to give that profile access.